# The fastest way to count differing elements in two long vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to compare 2 large vectors(integer) i.e. at each entry, see if two vectors have the same element or not. I've tried a few things, using an iterator to do the comparision and a simple for loop. Both works but I need something that will speed things up as I have to compare a lot of vectors. What's the best way to do that in C++?? Many thanks in advance!

```
typedef vector<int> fingerprint;

double aakernel(fingerprint a,fingerprint b, double h){

    double diff = 0;
    vector<int>::iterator dd = a.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator ee = b.begin();

    for(; dd != a.end() && ee != b.end() ;++dd, ++ee){ /*option one*/
        if (*dd!=*ee){
            diff++;
        }

    }


    for (int dd=0;dd<int(a.size());dd++){ /*option two*/
        if (a[dd]!=b[dd]){
            diff++;
        }
    }
    double due = (h/(1-h));
    double q = -log(due)*diff;
    double K = exp(q);
    return (K);
}
```

Comment: Are these vectors sorted?

Comment: Your question is vague, how do you want to compare? if they are totally equal? how many different elements? get the different elements? get symmetric difference?

Comment: @billz I'd say the goal is to compute the exponential based on the number of differing elements, as the OP's code does now.

Comment: @Angew It is a shame OP is asking a different question in the title and the text.

Comment: Why would `diff` be a `double`? I clearly can never take on non-integer values.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It's used as a `double` eventually. I am now processor hardware expert, but I'd guess it might be faster to compute in `double` from the start than do an `int -> double` conversion at the end.

Comment: The conversion at the end is practically irrelevant for speed since it's done only once per fingerprint-pair, whereas the increments happen inside a loop. In practise, that's unlikely to matter either, because `double` increment is also fast. Just conceptually, it's confusing to use a `double` for a mere counting job.

Comment: If there's more than 2^53 different elements then the `double` will actually get it wrong (since `++` will stop doing anything) whereas counting in `size_t` and converting to `double` at the end will get it less wrong. That's not likely to happen, of course, but using `double` just introduces more quirks.

Answer (score 3):

If the vectors are otherwise arbitrary, you cannot get asymptotically better than sequentially comparing all elements, the way you do now. So you're left with micro-optimisations which may or may not improve performance (depending on how your compiler's optimiser handles them).

The only one I can think of is taking the non-changing evaluations out of the loop. (And perhaps also not using `++` on type `double`, but I believe the compiler will handle this optimally anyway):

```
double diff = 0;
for (
  auto itA = a.begin(), itB = b.begin(), endA = a.end();
  itA != endA;
  ++itA, ++itB
) {
  if (*itA != *itB) {
    diff += 1.0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You could use speed this up by dividing it into pieces and using different threads for each.

2) You could also explore the parallel processing machine opcodes, such as MMX, to see if they're applicable.

3) Depending on your compiler, its optimiser, CPU etc. you may or may not find significant performance benefits just from eliminating the branching: instead of...

```
if (*dd != *ee){
    diff++;
}
```

...try perhaps...

```
diff += bool(*dd - *ee);
```

It might be worth checking the assembly language of the `if ()` version first to see if the optimiser is already doing this.  If `bool(*dd - *ee)` still has branches you could try a few other things, falling back on inline assembly if necessary.

4) assuming you'll end up comparing the same vector to many others, you could store checksums/hashes of ranges within the data, such that when the same vector is compared to different alternatives only the regions with differing hashes are considered: this could miss some differences - about 1 in 2^bits for a good hash - but if this is for fingerprints I assume it's probabilistic anyway and this will be insignificant.

5) if you're doing this for the NSA, I recommend recoding in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

In case the two `fingerprint` values are usually the same, it may help if you first do a

```
memcmp(&a[0], &b[0], a.size() * sizeof(int))
```

To test whether there's any difference between the two arrays at all. Only if there's any difference you go and look how many differences there are.

Comment: This can be generalised: if usually, the arrays are identical _save for a few spots_, then you can `memcmp` large-ish chunks and only go into details where there's a non-match.

Comment: @leftaroundabout You could do that via a divide-and-conquer approach, too: gradually test smaller chunks.

Comment: For what it's worth, you may also find that `a == b` does just a `memcmp` depending on how smart your compiler is. Unfortunately, mine doesn't seem to be smart enough even in release builds. :-/

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to write it by yourself since stl have certain functions to do that, check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)

You can check more algorithm here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/

Comment: A link is not an answer. How would you use `find_if` to count the number of differing elements between two vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all the different solutions! Much appreciated. I used diff as a double because at the end of the calculation it needs to be put in a kernel function and coming from a Python background I thought it would be better to assign it double in the first place but I might be wrong here but thanks for the comment!

Also, to elaborate on the fingerprint (which I should have done in the first place, my apologies) or maybe bitstring is a better word for it, each bit contains 1 or 0 in my case and I need to compare at each index whether the two bitstring are the same or not. Many thanks again for the solutions I'll try and see which one would help speed things up! Thanks a lot guys!